# Switching 'X' and 'Y' axes

Tags: plotting

Let's say, I have a function $y = f(x)$ which I want to plot on Mathematica in such a way that the traditional X-Axis is the Y-Axis and vice-versa.

I know that I can plot the function,

```
Plot[f(x), {x, x_min, x_max}, PlotRange[y_min, y_max]]
```

But is there is any way to plot the function in a way that after plotting the function the axes are switched?

I want to avoid the inverse functions since there would be some singularities that might pop out by doing that and I want to avoid that.

For example, $y = x^2$ would give me a parabola with directrix on X-Axis and focus on Y-Axis. I want to plot the same equation in such a way that the parabola opens towards the "right" instead of "up" in the traditional sense of the cartesian plane.

I hope I am clear. Thanks.

Comment: You could use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html). Try `ParametricPlot[{x^2, x}, {x, 0, 5}]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version
```

> `"13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`

```
f[x_] := x^3;
parplot1 = 
  ParametricPlot[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 50}}, ImageSize -> 200, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
parplot2 = 
  ParametricPlot[{f[x], x}, {x, 0, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> Reverse[PlotRange[parplot2]], ImageSize -> 200, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
Row[{parplot1, parplot2}, Spacer[100]]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 4):

@bmf gives a very practical solution.  Here is a more tricky way...

Given a plot whose axes you wish to interchange

```
g = Plot[Sin[π x], {x, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

do some internal fiddling

```
g /. {u_Line :> Map[Reverse, u, {2}],
     (v : (AxesOrigin | PlotRange) -> u_List) :> (v ->  Reverse[u])}
```

I did this by looking at the internal structure of `g` and working out where I needed to interchange `x` and `y`.

[image]

Comment: Very nice alternative approach (it was a (+1) since I saw it, but only now I got able to leave a comment :-) ).